# Seeking an example of a group with finite presentation for which the Word Problem is not solvable

Tags: group-theory, geometry, word-problem, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

In the book *Geometric Group Theory* of Clara Loh, it is proven that the [Word Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups) is solvable for hyperbolic groups. It is also stated that the Word Problem is not solvable in all finitely presented groups.

> Now I was searching for an example of such a group with finite presentation for which the Word Problem is not solvable, but I can't find one.

Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "*the* word problem"??  Which one?

Comment: For a finite presentation $\langle S|R \rangle$ of a group $G$, the word problem is solvable if there is an algorithm deciding for every word $w \in (S \cup S^{-1})^\ast$ whether it represents the trivial element of $G$ or not. Here the algorithm terminates on every input $w \in (S \cup S^{-1})^\ast$.

Comment: Put that in the QUESTION, of course.... not in a comment.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The word problem in a group is a very standard concept. It doesn't really need defining in the question. In fact the existence of a finite presentation is irrelevant. Solvable word problem just means that there is an algorithm for deciding whether an arbitrary word in the a generating set of the group represents the identity, and you can prove that this property is independent of the choice of generating set.

Comment: Constructing examples with unsolvable word problem is not easy. I would recommend Rotman's book on group theory for an accessible description. Somebody (I think Ian Chiswell) published a paper with an explicit presentation of such a group - I think it has about 22 generators.)

Comment: See [this relevant MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130274/example-of-a-group-with-unsolvable-word-problem). The hyperlink to the paper by Collins in that question isn't working right now, but [this link](http://doi.org/10.1215/ijm/1256044631) should work instead.

Comment: That was probably the example I was thinking of in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

As Derek mentioned, it's not easy, it was really hard to implement.

Nevertheless, let me somewhat mention relevant things:

1. For $I$ subset of $\mathbf{N}_{>0}$, let $G_I$ be the group presented with generators $t,x$ and relators $[x,t^ixt^{-i}]=1$ for $i\in I$.

It can be shown that $[x,t^ixt^{-i}]$ holds in $G$ if and only if $i\in I$. Hence, if $I$ is not computable, then $G_I$ doesn't have a solvable word problem.

It is obvious that if $I$ is recursively enumerable then $G_I$ is recursively presented. So if $I$ is recursively enumerable and not computable (i.e. the complement of $I$ is not recursively enumerable) then $G_I$ is recursively presented without solvable word problem.

Now a theorem of Higman is that every finitely generated recursively enumerable group embeds into a finitely presented group. If we take this as granted (this is hard!) we get a finitely presented group without solvable word problem.

Of course this Higman embedding theorem is a black box, but still this gives an indication what kind of phenomena can prevent a finitely presented group to be computable (=to have solvable word problem).

I should also mention that most results showing that some kind of computability problems is not solvable, consist in "encoding" solvability of the halting problem within the given kind of structure. For f.p. semigroups, it isn't that hard (to then produce non-computable f.p. semigroups, i.e., with non-solvable equality problem). For groups it's technically much more involved.

Comment: For example, $\langle a, b, c, d, e\mid ac=ca, ad=da, bc=cb, bd=db, eca=ce, edb=de, cca=ccae\rangle$ is a semigroup with undecidable word problem. Reference is: G.C. Tzeitin *Associative calculus with an unsolvable equivalence problem*, Tr. Mat. Inst. Akad. Nauk, 52 (1958), pp. 172-189.